# Почему не на каждой странице отображается шапка?

Tags: php, wordpress

[Сайт сделан на вордпресс](http://travelcluballadin.ru/). Вставил в header картинку, и шапка перестала отображаться на каждой странице. В чём может быть проблема?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wordpress`ом не пользовался, но у вас на главной странице картинка по адресу http://travelcluballadin.ru/head.png, а на остальных пытается загрузить картинку с http://travelcluballadin.ru/category/head.png

Comment: Большое спасибо. То, что нужно. А я чёто не догадался в код клянуть :)

Answer (score 0):

Не

```
<img src="head.png" width="964" height="297" border="0" usemap="#Map">
```

а

```
<img src="/head.png" width="964" height="297" border="0" usemap="#Map">
```